# visual studio Откатить публикацию

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Я опубликовал новую версию проекта, нажав кнопку "Опубликовать"(Web deploy). Но сайт отказался запускаться с ошибкой 502... Сейчас сайт не посещаем и находится в разработке, и я хочу на будущее узнать как можно моментально откатится до рабочей версии(в данном случае предыдущей), что бы разобраться с проблемой.

Как можно откатить версию публикации??

Как правильно тестировать перед окончательной публикацией? Нужно создать доп сервер(например ажур, я проверил, кстати, на ажур работает, в отличие от моего сервера...) или можно тестировать там же но в "режиме разработчика"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос имеет два аспекта и ответ тоже будет состоять из двух частей.

Во-первых, вам следует изучить средства версионного контроля (git, mercurial, tfs...). Если вы будете хранить исходники под версионным контролем то сможете всегда собрать исходники на любую нужную точку. Даже если просто начнёте изучать самые основы git (без веток) то это уже будет значительный шаг вперёд: не заработала текущая версия - вернулись к предыдущему коммиту, собрали публикацию - выложили.

Во-вторых, нужно понимать, что если "на моём компьютере работает, а на продакшене нет", то вам нужно задуматься о том, чтобы уметь собирать/развёртывать одинаковые конфигурации. Современные средства для этого - докеры и прочие контейнеры.

Бонусы. Дополнительно поможет пирамида тестирования. От юнит-тестов до интеграционных. Дополнительные бонусы можно извлечь из средств continious integration (сборка исходников и их автоматическая публикация).

Comment: я бы ещё добавил то, что имея билд сервер и возможности деплоя с него, можно будет собирать любую версию вашего приложения из исходников и не только тестировать её, но и деплоить. То есть собрали новый релиз - протестировали - задеплоили, не понравилось - пересобрали старый релиз (или взяли прошлую его сборку) и задеплоили не место новой - получили откат к предыдущей версии за пару кликов мыши.